# How to wrap every n'th div using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have achieved this with jQuery, but I am looking for a solution with plain JavaScript. I have a div structure like this -

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>

... and so on
```

Now, I want to wrap every nth div inside every `.parent` div. Like this -

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>content</div>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</div>

... and so on
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have tried something like this and stuck with no further clue -

```
// forEach function
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need
    }
}

// select all .parent divs
var parentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

//slicing the array
var chunk = function ( array, size ) {
  var arr = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += size ) {
      var newSlicedArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( array, i, i + size );
      Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, newSlicedArray);
  }
  return arr;
}

//run foreach function
forEach(parentDivs, function (index, value) {

  var childrens = value.querySelectorAll("div");

  var final = chunk(childrens,1);
  console.log(final);

});
```

Comment: As a start: `Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, newSlicedArray);` -> `arr.push(newSlicedArray)`, `chunk(children, 1)` -> `chunk(children, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prototype call was unnecessary for the push.  It's a native array and not a DOM element.
Added code to map the arrays to arrays of DOM elements, accumulate and append them to a new DOM elements and remove from parent using reduce, and then append back to the original element.

```js
// forEach function
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need
    }
}

// select all .parent divs
var parentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

//slicing the array
var chunk = function ( array, size ) {
  var arr = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += size ) {
      var newSlicedArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( array, i, i + size );
      arr.push(newSlicedArray);
  }
  return arr;
}

//run foreach function
forEach(parentDivs, function (index, value) {

  var childrens = value.querySelectorAll("div");

  var final = chunk(childrens,3);
  final.map( towrap => 
     towrap.reduce( (acc, el) => 
        (acc.appendChild(el),acc) , document.createElement('div') )
  ).forEach( el => {
    el.className ="wrap";
    value.appendChild(el)
  })

});
```

```css
.wrap { border: 1px solid green }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.removeChild(el)` is unnecessary