# How to create rows for every 3rd item using for each?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a grid using `forEach`. What i am after is to be able to wrap items into rows of 3. How would i do that?

Here's my current code:

```
        this.el = document.getElementById('feed')

        const releases = data.Releases //array of items
        const list = document.createDocumentFragment()

        releases.forEach((release, index) => {
          let item = document.createElement('div')

          let a = document.createElement('a')
          let title = document.createElement('h2')
          let date = document.createElement('time')

          title.innerHTML = `${release.Title}`
          date.innerHTML = `${release.PublishDate}`
          a.setAttribute('href', release.EncryptedId)
          
          a.appendChild(date)
          a.appendChild(title)
          item.appendChild(a)
          list.appendChild(item)
        })

        this.el.appendChild(list)
```

Expected output:

```
<div id="feed">
  <div>
    <div><a href="">1<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
    <div><a href="">2<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
    <div><a href="">3<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><a href="">4<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
    <div><a href="">5<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
    <div><a href="">6<h2></h2><time></time></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `for (..., i += 2) {}` instead of map?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap every n'th div using plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346567/how-to-wrap-every-nth-div-using-plain-javascript)

Comment: For reasons i have to use map, so no, not really.

Comment: Do you mean a li has 3 rows of data? Or does each list has 3 items?

Comment: I mean a list having rows of 3 items each.

Comment: Are you sure you understand the `map`-function? Right now you're using it for a `forEach`-replacement. I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map After that please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am sure, yes.

Comment: @MathAdams then you know that you're using `map` incorrectly, as `map` needs a `return` statement? Anyways, see the link posted by Justinas. You'll need to split up your `releases` array in multiple smaller arrays where each smaller array represents a row.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ha! obviously i was not sure then..

Comment: I have now edited my code.

Comment: Ok, you made an edit in your code, but your title and body still contain the question to ask for a map. This is really confusing ATM. Please take your time to edit your question as good as possible..

Comment: My bad, now corrected.

Comment: It's unfortunately still unclear what you are going after. Can you outline the desired HTML result in your question?

Comment: Do you need to include three `a` elements in the same `li` element?

Comment: Code updated again. Was a little fast while mentioning the UL stuff. It's ofc divs.

Comment: Your expected output does not have `h2` and `time` elements.

Comment: I think everyone gets the concept. But added in case not.

Comment: Pull `item` _declaration_ outside of the `forEach` callback function. In the function, create and append a new `item` (were it finally `li` or `div`) only when `!index % 3` is `true`. This is probably the same idea Abdul has implemented in their answer, that lacks some important details, though.

Comment: @Teemu Dou you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the structure of your data based on how you need it to be. In this case you'll want something that resembles the following structure:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3]
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [...],
  ...
]
```

So you'll have to divide your array in to *chunks* of 3. You can write a function for this which does just that. Here's one for example:

```
const toChunks = (array, size) => 
  Array(Math.ceil(array.length / size)).fill()
  .map((entry, index) => index * size)
  .map(begin => array.slice(begin, begin + size));
```

Apply that to your data and loop over the nested array. In the outer loop, create a `div` which. Then in the inner loop, create the rest of the elements and append them to the `div`. Then append the `div` to the `list`.

```
const list = document.createDocumentFragment();

const releases = data.Releases; //array of items
const releasesChunks = toChunks(releases, 3);

for (const releasesChunk of releasesChunks) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  for (const release of releasesChunk) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const title = document.createElement('h2');
    const date = document.createElement('time');

    a.href = release.EncryptedId;
    title.textContent = release.Title;
    date.textContent = release.PublishDate;
          
    a.append(date, title);
    item.append(a);
    wrapper.append(item);
  }

  list.append(wrapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a new row is created every time the index is divisible by 3. This row is then appended to the list. The items are appended to the last row in the list. The 'row' variable keeps track of the current row.

```
releases.forEach((release, index) => {
  if (index % 3 === 0) {
    row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    list.appendChild(row);
  }
```

Comment: This ignores 2/3 of data. OP needs three "items" per line (an item being `<a><h2></h2><time></time></a>`).

Comment: Also, `ul` cannot have `div` children.

Comment: Hi, thanks! See my updated code in the first post.